# struct containing a function pointer with itself as a return type in C

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers

Got the following data struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    lamp *lamp;
    unsigned char a;
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned char d;
    unsigned char e;
    void (*func)(struct event *);
} event;
```

The last line inside the struct is supposed to be a pointer to a function with return type void with pointer to an event as an argument such as:

```
void function(event *evt);
```

Though, I get the following warning message: "its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want". Is this right or wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your struct needs needs to be defined like this:

```
typedef struct event  // <<< note the `event` tag here
{
    lamp *lamp;
    unsigned char a;
    unsigned char b;
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned char d;
    unsigned char e;
    void (*func)(struct event *);
} event;              // <<< you can still keep `event` as a typedef
                      //     which is equivalent to `struct event`
```

Comment: like @Paul said typedef struct MyStruct {
    [...]
} AliasForMyStruct;